# preg_replace on the actual match ( index 1) instead of whole string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Consider

```
preg_replace('/(lets go).*/', "going", "lets go somewhere")
```

It will output: "going", I want "going somewhere".

`preg_replace` seems to replace using the first match which is the whole string "lets go somewhere". How can I make it ignore index 0 and only target index 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you want to match with `.*`. You don't need it. This will work fine:

```
preg_replace('/(lets go)/', "going", "lets go somewhere");
```

Or you can use a lazy match:

```
preg_replace('/(lets go).*?/', "going", "lets go somewhere");
```

Explanation: Your original expression was greedy. That roughly means that `.*` matches as many characters as possible. `.*?` is lazy; it matches the minimum amount of characters.

You can also match 'somewhere' as a sub-pattern, and us it in the replacement:

```
preg_replace('/(lets go)(.*)/', "going\$2", "lets go somewhere");
```

Here. $0 is "lets go somewhere", $1 is "lets go", $2 is " somewhere". The backslash is needed because "going\$2" is inside double quotes.

Comment: The lazy match solves my problem ( .* just illustrates some more content in the regex). Im not sure I understand it though its OUTSIDE of the paranthesis so it shouldnt be matched at all no mather what? Edit: i guess there is a difference between capturing and matching I need to grasp. Thanks!

Comment: The parentheses group sub-patterns. `preg_replace` will replace the entire pattern. But could also use a sub-pattern as a replacement. I'll put an example in my answer.